# Python Selenium Webdriver: No Such Element or Element not Visible or InvalidSelectorException

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to access an button in browser with the Name export via selenium web driver. I have tried with the xpath

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='tb-btn']//[contains(text(), 'Export')]").click()` for this i get the error InvalidSelectorException.

when i tried  `driver.find_element_by_xpath("*//[contains(text(), 'Export')]").click()` for this i get the error Element Not Visible.

When i tried `driver.find_element_by_xpath("*//[@id="master_btnExport"]").click()` i get No such Element.

This is the image of the url when inspect the element
[image]

Not sure why i get these errors. Any inputs would be really helpful.

[image]

[image]

Regards,
Ren.

Comment: Have you checked for frames? Try to give some delay before clicking on it... User WebDriverWait for element getting visible or clickable...

Comment: [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481). Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Try either of following two Xpath.It should work.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='master_btnExport']")
```

Or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='tb-btn-0link-left']")
```

If you want to give some time to load for element to be available try that.

```
 WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='master_btnExport']")))
```

OR

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='master_btnExport']")))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: When i tried the above code it gives me a syntax error. So i changed it `wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@id='master_btnExport']"))).click()` for it to work. Post that i get this error `NameError: name 'ExpectedConditions' is not defined`. Is there anyother module that i need to import from selenium

Comment: You have to import this class ```import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;```

Comment: Thanks i had it imported as  ExpectedConditions as EC so i was not recognizing it. Also the python module does not have `visibilityOfElementLocated`

Comment: Thanks Kajal, the funny part is now even though i have give wait for 60 and already i can see the export icon in the browser i am getting the timeout exception. `     79                 break
---> 80         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
     81 
     82     def until_not(self, method, message=''):

TimeoutException: Message: `

Comment: I guess some iframe is there? Could you please check and let me know if any iframe is there on the html page.

Comment: I am adding the image from Chrome and it for your reference in the main post.

Comment: Yes my guess is right.Search ```iframe``` and give the Id or name here.

Comment: You have to switch to Iframe first then will above code work.Send me ```iframe``` name attribute value or post snapshot ```iframe``` search content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188441/discussion-between-kajal-kundu-and-ren-lyke).

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you either give a wrong path to an element or your script runs before actually letting that element load

Comment: Please elaborate